# Trigger jenkins job when we received mail in outlook

Tags: jenkins, outlook

I have a jenkins job `test` in my local machine.

Whenever I receive the mail having specified subject line like `trigger job for $arg` in Outlook, immediately it should trigger jenkins job by passing parameter `$arg`.

Could you please help me on this. If i'm not clear please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

You can start a build job with parameters through a URL  ie.

**http:/server/jenkins/job/jobname/buildWithParameters?PARM1=Value1&PARM2=Value2**

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the quick response but here my question is once i receive the mail it should trigger automatically. How can i do this?

Comment: Ya we can trigger the Jenkins from the webhook config, but what setting should be done on the outlook to trigger